# How can I generate a GridView or DataGrid using only C# in a Command Line application?

Tags: c#

I am adding on to a command line program that really just runs automatically on a server, sends a daily email with a transaction total every day.

What I would like to add to the email is a DataGrid or GridView like in ASP.NET, displaying specific company names and their totals (rather than just a total number for everyone).

I think I can figure how to get the data from the db and use it for this but I'm not sure how to put a Grid together for the email body. I know I could put the HTML in the email body for a table but how could I populate it dynamically with information?

I've seen tutorials with web applications that will do this from an event handler, basically sending the same GridView from a web form but I would like to do this from a basic command line application alone.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

```
var body = "Good Morning --<br/><br/>Yesterday, " +
    DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("dddd") + " " +
    DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString() +
    " there were " + count.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) +
    " payments processed with a total of " +
    paymentAmount + "<br /><br />" + 
    "Please visit <a href=\"" + url + "?date=" +
    DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString().Replace("/", "-") +
    "\" title=\"Click here to view the transactions.\">" + url +
    "</a> to view the transactions." + "<br /><br />Company Totals:<br />";

// create and populate a datagrid programatically for insertion into our email
body += "Grid goes here";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an `HtmlTable`, which is a .net object, dynamically add rows and add cells to those rows. Then render the `HtmlTable` object to a string and add it to your email text.

```
var table = new HtmlTable();
var tr = new HtmlTableRow();
tr.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell { InnerText = "Cell Text" });
table.Rows.Add(tr);
```

You can create the entire table this way.

Then you can use this function to convert the table to plain text

```
private static string RenderTableToString(HtmlTable table)
{
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (var htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            table.RenderControl(htw);
            var html = sw.ToString();
            return html;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: To be able to use the HtmlTable object you need to add a reference to `System.Web` and add the using statement to the application.

`using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;`

Comment: I think this would be the best approach for me. Mainly writing for ASP.NET, I was unaware of the HtmlTable object but this is nice to know. As @The Mouth of a Cow mentioned, I will probably end up converting to plain text anyway. At least for the table. I appreciate it.

Comment: Excellent.  I think that's probably the best route for your particular situation.

Comment: Hmm, it seems HtmlTable is not recognized when I try to add it to my command line application. Is this for asp.net?

Comment: You may have to add a reference to `System.Web` to your project.

Comment: I would like to think so but It still doesn't seem to recognize it. Even after refactoring.

Comment: You also have to add the using statement as well `using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;`

Comment: Ok..intellisense just needed time to catch up I guess. System.Web.UI.HtmlControl worked

Comment: Awesome!  I'll update the answer to reflect this.  It really should have been there to begin with.

Comment: No problem. I appreciate the input.

Comment: anytime, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Automated emails like this should almost certainly be written in plain text; much easier to create and much less likely to go wrong. A decent email client (and a lot of not decent ones) will recognise and parse those URLs for you and will display plain text emails in a fixed width font so you can write tabular data directly in text.

My vote would be to do something very simple like just using fixed width formatting for your tabular data based on what you guess will look right (or if you really care you could precompute the appropriate width).

See [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/07/21/formatting-text-files.aspx) for details on how to do this.

Comment: Amazingly the windows 8 metro mail client won't parse urls.  I'm not knocking your solution, just voicing my frustration with it.

Comment: Hilarious! Well I did say decent email client! The Metro UI experiment is one of the most ill conceived in the entire history of software engineering. My favourite thing about Win 8(.1) so far is that there is no way to copy and paste both a username and password into the VPN settings window. You can paste one of them, but not both because the stupid window shuts when you change context to copy the other. Win 8 is Vista all over again, the next one will be better.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this problem would be as follows:

1. Create a text template file with placeholders
2. Read the text file and replace all placeholders with the values
3. Send the content in the email

The template file will look something like

```
Good Morning --<br/><br/>
Yesterday, {YesterdayDate} {YesterdayTime} there were {countOfPaymentProcessed} payments processed with a total of {paymentTotal} paymentAmount <br /><br />
Please visit <a href="{url}?date={YesterdayDate}" title="Click here to view the transactions.> {url}</a> to view the transactions.<br /><br />
Company Totals:{companyTotalsTable}<br />
```

To read and email this content, I would have done the following:

```
string templateText = File.ReadToEnd(@"file/path/and/fileName");
// replace the placeholders with values

// create table as by passing DataReader/DataSet or any other object to the function that returns html Table's HTML

// code to email the content
```